# Mounted device taking up space on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have an Ubuntu based Droplet on DigitalOcean which has 25GB of Storage. I am using it to run Backups from 2 different Machines.

- Backup 1 is going to /home/server1/ (should have a total of 25GB of
  disk available)
- Backup 2 is goint to /mnt/volume_sgp1_01/server2/ (this should be the VOLUMES part
  of 200GB)

Since 25GB are not enough for my scope I have added a VOLUMES plan, which gave me an additional 200GB on a mounted drive, the problem now however seems that the mounted device also takes up space on the main droplet. Here an example:

```
    4.0K    lib64
    4.0K    media
    4.0K    opt
    4.0K    srv
    8.0K    snap
    16K     lost+found
    32K     root
    40K     tmp
    608K    run
    5.3M    etc
    15M     bin
    15M     sbin
    76M     boot
    171M    lib
    855M    usr
    1.3G    var
    6.5G    home
    14G     mnt
    23G     total
```

The 14GB of mnt seem to be used / allocated on my Droplet as well, however that should not be the case.

I have added the SPACES (mnt) using the original instructions being:

```
    # Create a mount point for your volume:
    $ mkdir -p /mnt/volume_sgp1_01

    # Mount your volume at the newly-created mount point:
    $ mount -o discard,defaults,noatime /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_volume-sgp1-01 /mnt/volume_sgp1_01

    # Change fstab so the volume will be mounted after a reboot
    $ echo '/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_volume-sgp1-01 /mnt/volume_sgp1_01 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

I am not really a LINUX expert, however I think there is definately something wrong here, perhaps I mounted it incorrectly or why is mnt using up disk space on my 25GB? Some expert help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `du` does not care about mounts. It sums all given files and directories. If you want to see only what's on your root partition use the parameter `--one-file-system` (or `-x`).

Comment: Thanks for the information, however if I log in over SSH I get:  Usage of /:   94.9% of 24.06GB and I get a low disk space message

Comment: You may want to unmount /mnt/volume_sgp1_01 and run `du -hd1 /mnt` to see if there's anything in the actual /mnt directory that's using space.